# Using Google Play In-App purchases in Amazon store, can it be done?

Tags: unity, google-play-services, appstore, in-app-purchase

I have an app currently in the play store (it's free), and google play IAPs are implemented in the app.

I'm new to the Amazon store, but if it allows me to upload an APK as is, what is to prevent my game from allowing users to make in app purchases via google play using an app they downloaded off Amazon? Would I be absolutely required to set up IAPs for Amazon if I use their store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you are doing it seperately. Apps are identified with different app ID in different stores and transactions are done with related to it as well as to merchant accounts.

In app purchase feature is now [unified](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAP.html) in 5.4.0 with amazon app store too.

[Soomla](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/6103) is paid but for all platforms as well.

Comment: If I am just removing ads with IAP, cant I use Google IAP? it is eventually just removing ads.

Comment: You can always use Unity's integrated IAP setup. If you are trying for amazon app store separately for some reason then you are probably looking for [Amazon In-app purchase plugin for Unity](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/in-app-purchasing-unity-plug-in)